# How to remove users that have roles scoped to a specific Azure AD Administrative Unit via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to understand the correct PowerShell command to remove one or more users which have a role granted to them which is scoped over the members of an Administrative Unit.
For example, a Help Desk Employee that is empowered with Authentication Administrator over an AU that contains all the staff at their office location.

It would appear that the correct way to do this using Azure AD Powershell would be to use Remove-AzureADMSScopedRoleMembership but I cannot find any documentation on what inputs are desired for this command or if this is even the right method to reach the desired outcome.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadmsscopedrolemembership?view=azureadps-2.0

Iterations I have tried:

Remove-AzureADMSScopedRoleMembership -id "Object ID of user with scoped role" -ScopedRoleMembershipId "/administrativeUnits/ObjectId of AU"

Remove-AzureADMSScopedRoleMembership : Error occurred while executing RemoveMSScopedRoleMembership
Code: BadRequest
Message: Resource not found for the segment

Remove-AzureADMSScopedRoleMembership -id "Object ID of AU with scoped roles" -ScopedRoleMembershipId "Object ID of user with scoped role"

Remove-AzureADMSScopedRoleMembership : Error occurred while executing RemoveMSScopedRoleMembership
Code: BadRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadscopedrolemembership?view=azureadps-2.0-preview):

Firstly, I have added a scopedrole as below:

```
    Connect-AzureAD
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Display Name of User"
    $Role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -EQ -Value "User Administrator"
    $RoleMember = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMemberInfo
    $Unit = Get-AzureADAdministrativeUnit | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -Eq -Value Test
    $RoleMember.ObjectId = $User.ObjectID
    Add-AzureADScopedRoleMembership -ObjectId  $unit.ObjectId -RoleObjectId $Role.ObjectId -RoleMemberInfo $RoleMember
```

[image]

[image]

I have taken `ScopedRoleMembershipId` from microsoft Graph api using below request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/administrativeUnits/{admin-unit-id}/scopedRoleMembers
```

[image]

Then used below command to remove user and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadscopedrolemembership?view=azureadps-2.0-preview):

```
Remove-AzureADScopedRoleMembership  -ObjectId   $unit.ObjectId  -ScopedRoleMembershipId "08ovlLXBT0CMQ7kJaZRJU"
```

[image]

[image]

Try to follow the above process user will be removed as mine got.